# Pass multiple variables to content script chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm writing my first chrome extension, and I just started this a few hours ago. Everything worked well when it was hard-coded. Essentially, I'm filling an 8-page form. Each page of the form corresponds to a separate content script. The content scripts used to look something like this: (finding the fields is a bit more difficult, since they're not standard, but I'm not worried about that..that part works)

```
var first_name = 'John';
var last_name = 'Doe';
...
...
document.getElementById('first_name').value = first_name;
document.getElementById('last_name').value = last_name;
```

This worked fine (for me), but I want to distribute it to a few people, none of whom would/could use the extension from source code, editing the variables directly. So I made an 'Options' page, using this as an example:
https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/options.html

The options page is a mockup of the form to be filled, and each user can enter their defaults here. My save_options() function basically does (pseudocode):

```
foreach(fields as field) {
    localStorage[field] = document.getElement....(field);
}
```

This works fine. It saves properly, displays the stored values, etc.

The problem comes when I try to access the variables from the content script. From what I've read, this can't be done (directly), and there are various methods online that show how to do this. I want to do something like this (content script):

```
var first_name = localStorage["first_name"];
var last_name = localStorage["last_name"];
...
...
document.getElementById('first_name').value = first_name;
document.getElementById('last_name').value = last_name;
```

My questions are:

1) For those of you who have dealt with Chrome extensions/localstorage/chrome.storage/etc, is there a 'best' way to do this?

2) What is the most efficient way to set all the variable names/values? I'd prefer a loop (like above) over setting each field with a separate request. I'm averaging 10 fields per page.

(I could probably use a long, messy form of http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html, but I'm hoping for a more efficient/extensible/elegant solution)

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: From what I've read, content scripts aren't able to access localStorage (sandboxed). Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh well, if that is the case, you could obtain things via [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to a background script.

Comment: chrome.extension.sendMessage({
            greeting: "hello"
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });

Comment: edit.. Actually, I think I got the hang of it... Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to use Messaging Passing, which you've mentioned.

Another (better, I think) solution is `chrome.storage` API (See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html for more information). The Storage API can be directly used in both background pages and content scripts and Chrome will automatically synced if you store values under `chrome.storage.sync`. The only substantial difference from localStorage is that this API is asynchronous, so you have to write you code like

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['first_name', 'last_name'], function(items){
    document.getElementById('first_name').value = items['first_name'];
    document.getElementById('last_name').value = items['last_name'];
});
```